# Split Express App into multiple Files results in 500 Server Error

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So for clarity, I wanted to split my functions into separate files based on the part of my API it handles. I followed a tutorial online but now when I try to access any url on the api, it results in a 500 server error with no visible error message.

So, my `index.ts` file is simple and handles all the express routing.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use('/v1', app);
main.use(bodyParser.json());

const {
    getVendors,
    getVendor
} = require('./vendors');

module.exports = {
    'webApi' : functions.https.onRequest(main),
    'get-vendors' : app.get('/vendors', getVendors),
    'get-vendor' : app.get('/vendors/:id', getVendor)
}
```

Followed by my `admin.ts` which handles the one time only init of admin firebase.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

module.exports = {
    database,
}
```

And finally, `vendors.ts` that of course, holds all of the CRUD functions for `vendors`. (I only included the first two functions for simplicity)

```
const {
    db,
} = require('./admin');

const getVendors = async (request:any, response:any) => {
    try {
        const vendorQuerySnapshot = await db.collection('vendors').get();
        const vendors: any = [];
        vendorQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc:any) => {
            vendors.push({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            });
        });
        response.json(vendors);
    } catch(error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
}

const getVendor = async (request:any, response:any) => {
    try {
        const vendorId = request.params.id;

        if(!vendorId) throw new Error('Vendor ID is required');

        const vendor = await db.collection('vendors').doc(vendorId).get();

        if(!vendor.exists) {
            throw new Error('Vendor doesnt exist.');
        }

        response.json({
            id: vendor.id,
            data: vendor.data()
        });
    } catch(error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
}
```

Again, I'm receiving a `500 Internal Server Error` whenever I try to access http://my-url.com/v1/** where `**` in this case would equal `vendors` or `vendor/:id`

**UPDATE**

I felt it's important to note that prior to following the tutorial and splitting the files everything worked as expected.

**UPDATE**

I added a `console.log(error)` to the `catch` of `getVendor` and it appears to be an issue with `db`.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at getVendors (/srv/lib/vendors.js:6:46)
```

Removing the `admin.ts` file and placing the contents into the `vendors.ts` file, makes everything work. However, it can't be declared more than once so it's not a solid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is not being imported into db correctly it seems as db is turning up as undefinded.

Try

```
db = require('./admin');
```

instead of

```
const {
    db,
} = require('./admin');
```

Additionally, try to export your database as

```
module.exports = database
```

instead of

```
module.exports = {
    database,
}
```